# Kubernetes networking

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I'm studying kubernetes and I'm currently trying to create an Ingress with two paths, one on a service called "java-app-service" and another on "test-service". I can reach java-app-service but I get Bad Gatheway on test app, why?
Here java-app-service:

```
  apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: java-app
  name: java-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: java-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort
```

test-service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-app
  name: test-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort
```

And my Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: java-app-ingress
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - hostname: my-app
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: my-app
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: java-app-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /test/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Service are all up, plus here my deployment for java-app:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: java-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: java-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: java-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: java-app
          image: aquatrale/demo2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

and test-app:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: test-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test-pod
      namespace: default
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test-app
          image: aquatrale/test:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt 1:**

Try to set names for your ports at your `Services`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  ...
spec:
  ports:
  - name: my-app-port
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

And reference it from your `Ingresss` by that names:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ...
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ...
    http:
      paths:
      - path: ...
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-app
            port:
              name: my-app-port
```

**Attempt 2:**

Try to remove the trailing `/` from your second path ( `/test/` ).

According to [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples) it should also match all subpaths including the "main" path (without trailing slash) of your second service.

Comment: It doesn't work that way either :(

Comment: Okay, another try. Maybe the trainling slash of your second path is causing the problem.

Comment: Tried with "/test" and i get 502 bad gateway